# Problem with monitoring multiple OPC UA nodes

Tags: javascript, node.js, opc-ua, opc, node-opcua

**Current behavior**

In a client, when monitoring multiple nodes using a `forEach` loop, only two nodes get monitored on version 2.30.0 and only one in 2.72.2 while the array that generates the loop contains 5 items.

Behaviour in 2.30.0

[image]

Bahaviour in 2.72.2

[image]

UA Expert screenshot for reference
[image: ua_expert screenshot]

**Expected behavior**

The expected behavior is that all the item nodes get processed.

**Code source for the reproduction of the problem**

```js
const idsToMonitor = ["ns=4;i=16", "ns=4;i=17", "ns=4;i=11", "ns=4;i=12", "ns=4;i=18"]
const monitoringParamaters = {
        samplingInterval: 100,
        discardOldest: true,
        queueSize: 10,
    };
    idsToMonitor.forEach((nodeId) => {
        opc_subscription.monitor({
            nodeId: resolveNodeId(nodeId),
            attributeId: AttributeIds.Value,
        },
        monitoringParamaters,
        TimestampsToReturn.Both,
        (err, monitoredItem) => {
            monitoredItem.on("changed", function (dataValue) {
            var Node = {nodeId: nodeId, nodeName: "111" , nodeValue: dataValue.value.value , nodeTimestamp: dataValue.sourceTimestamp.toISOString()};
            console.log(JSON.stringify(Node));
        });
    });
});
```

**Please tell us about your environment:**

- [X] my request is related to node-opcua acting as a  OPCUA CLIENT
- [X] I have installed node-opcua as a package ( using npm install )
- OS version: Windows 10

- **Node:**
  `node --version` = 16.16.0